# Is there any way to keep Windows Explorer from making redundant windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there a way to tell Windows to only have one instance of Explorer per folder path?

For example, sometimes I don't realize that I have a folder open but minimized, so I open another instance (by double clicking a shortcut that I have made). When I do that, I have two identical windows open to the same path. Instead of doing that, I would like it to just maximize the first one.   Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is confusing as written - are you referring to opening multiple instances of Windows Explorer simultaneously?

Comment: make a folder on the desktop, double click on it, minimize it, double click on the desktop icon again, now you have 2, whereas it would be nice if it was smart enough to realize that the first one was already open.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought you were trying to say.  I've taken the liberty of editing your question to be more readable.

Comment: what is the shortcut to? mine behaves exactly as you are looking for. (it restores the already open window)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if there are some programm conficts. If this behaviour changed sort time ago please try to set you system back to an older date ( system restore points http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore).

You also could try to create a new user and check if the problem exists there as well.

If none of both works please post the following registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder
```

1. Press start Button and enter regedit
2. Please look for the given Path
3. When the folder is marked press "File" and then export
4. After you saved the file you can rightclick the file(s) and click on edit
5. Copy the content and paste it here